# I have a function which changes dictionary keys to uppercase, but the function will miss some key

Tags: python, dictionary, key

In this case, I want to change all dictionary keys to uppercase.

My dict looks like this:

> dt={'case_a': 'EF57A48C', 'case_b': {'case_b_a': 5, 'case_b_b': 3}, 'case_c': {'case_c_a': {'case_c_a_a': 1, 'case_c_a_b': 20, 'case_c_a_c': 'sensor/pos/ss1', 'case_c_a_d': 0, 'case_c_a_e': 1}, 'case_c_b': {'case_c_b_a': 1, 'case_c_b_b': -1, 'case_c_b_c': 'sensor/pos/ss2', 'case_c_b_d': 99, 'case_c_b_e': 1}, 'case_c_c': {'case_c_c_a': 2, 'case_c_c_b': 20, 'case_c_c_c': 'sensor/pos/ss1', 'case_c_c_d': -1, 'case_c_c_e': 1}}}

Function:

```
def T_change(payload=dict()):
    for key ,value in payload.items():
        if isinstance(value,dict):
            payload[str(key).upper()]=T_change(payload.pop(key))
        else:
            payload[str(key).upper()]=payload.pop(key)
    return payload
```

Execute:

> T_change(dt)

Result:

> {'CASE_A': 'EF57A48C', 'CASE_B': {'CASE_B_A': 5, 'CASE_B_B': 3}, 'CASE_C': {'CASE_C_A': {'**case_c_a_b**': 20, 'CASE_C_A_E': 1, 'CASE_C_A_A': 1, 'CASE_C_A_C': 'sensor/pos/ss1', 'CASE_C_A_D': 0}, 'CASE_C_B': {'**case_c_b_b**': -1, 'CASE_C_B_E': 1, 'CASE_C_B_A': 1, 'CASE_C_B_C': 'sensor/pos/ss2', 'CASE_C_B_D': 99}, 'CASE_C_C': {'**case_c_c_b**': 20, 'CASE_C_C_E': 1, 'CASE_C_C_A': 2, 'CASE_C_C_C': 'sensor/pos/ss1', 'CASE_C_C_D': -1}}}

I want to change all dictionary keys to uppercase, but I don't know why is the function missing some of the keys?

Comment: works correctly for me...

Comment: This code was working successful when i update the code below.


def T_change(payload=dict()):
    dt=dict()
    for key ,value in payload.items():
        if isinstance(value,dict):
            dt.update({str(key).upper():T_change(payload[key])})
        else:
            dt.update({str(key).upper():payload[key]})
    return dt

Comment: @Randolph also, `dict()` is not recommended (Python talk at FOSDEM 2017), use `dt = {}` https://doughellmann.com/blog/2012/11/12/the-performance-impact-of-using-dict-instead-of-in-cpython-2-7-2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you perform `pop` you change order of the dictionary, and for loop works using order. So when you will pop `case_c_a_a` to work with, it will become last element of the dict after performing operations and `case_c_a_b` will become first. As first element of the dict is already worked, it will switch to next element, `case_c_a_c` without working on `case_c_a_b`. To understand it better, use http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html

Solution for you problem will be to make new dictionary in function and use return statement (will work for recursive call too). That will solve problem.